# How to use "takeStringValueFrom" with Button onclick Event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a button that correctly wired such that when it is clicked, the "login" IBAction is hit.

```
- (IBAction) login: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
```

Now, I wired the button to the username/password text fields using "takeStringValueFrom" but I don't understand how to then get at those values?

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT: so basically, when i click the "login" button the above event fires. I'd like to grab the values from two text boxes on that same window, what is the best way to accomplish this? I suppose I could use IBOutlet for each of the text boxes ... is this the correct way?

Re-reading [the doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/takeStringValueFrom:), it's possible "takeStringValueFrom" isn't what i thought it was.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your sitution? I'm not sure what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to declare your username and password textfields as `IBOutlet`s, and then hook them up in Interface Builder.  Then, in your `login` handler, you use the `stringValue` message to extract their values:

```
- (IBAction) login: (id)sender
{
    NSString *username = [usernameTextField stringValue];
    NSString *password = [passwordTextField stringValue];

    // check username & password
}
```